# Can't Connect to MariaDB Database from Visual Studio Express 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, mariadb

I've consulted the Microsoft and MySQL websites, but none of the fixes I found dealt with both MariaDB and VB Express 2015. Anything from a link to a step-by-step guide would be welcomed at this point. The most usual error I get is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)"

I think the error is something to do with this section:

```
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection()

    cn.ConnectionString = "Server=IP:PORT;Database=dbname;Uid=username;Pwd=password;"
    cn.Open()
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong data providers.  The error message indicates SQL Server, but MariaDB is a form of MySQL.  You need the MySql NET connector

Comment: I was indeed missing the MySql NET connector. Thank you @Plutonix